# Cross Browser Utility to Encourage Users to "Allow Camera & Microphone"

Tags: html, user-interface, camera, user-experience

When we ask the user to allow us to use their Camera and Microphone the browser presents some sort of interface asking the user to accept or reject this action.

In Google Chrome this interface looks like this:

[image: ... wants to user your camera and microphone]

Our users seem to be missing the appearance of these `Deny` and `Allow` buttons.

Is there any cross browser utility that serves as *"visual encouragement"* for the user to click allow?

For instance, in the case of Google Chrome, something like a big yellow arrow would appear in the upper right of the page window and point at "Allow".

Answer (score 1):

Agree that the default presentation in the major browsers leaves a lot to be desired. That pop-down menu bar is (typically) visually isolated from whatever the user clicked on to trigger the permission request. That is, their locus of attention is on an element that's disconnected from what they need to do next. This problem is exacerbated (1) by banner blindness (which means that people are used to ignoring animations in their peripheral vision, assuming that it's an ad) and (2) on larger screens.

So those are the issues causing the problem.

Here's a quick video walkthrough of one way to solve the problem by the site and by the browser itself, using Google Maps' "use my location" feature in the web browser:

http://cl.ly/2h2f382A143F/so-browserpermissions.m4v

[image: Letterbox effect created by the requesting site]

[image: Browser requests permission near the locus of attention]

Comment: The first screenshot is essentially exactly the UX which I was imagining. I was hoping that there would be a quick plugin which already existed for this purpose.